# Sort an String-Array in the right order

Tags: java, sorting

I have tried to sort my array in the right order. I have stored 3 variables (1 `int`, 1 `String`, 1 `float`) in one field of the array. I have tried to use the native sort method, but my output is not sorted the right way:

```
[1 ,Agavendicksaft  ,0.180
, 1 ,Agavendicksaft  ,0.284
, 100 ,Röstzwiebel ,0.057
, 103 ,Salz fein ,6.220
, 103 ,Salz fein ,6.452
, 104 ,Salz grob ,0.490
, 114 ,Sesam ,0.735
, 114 ,Sesam ,1.742
, 115 ,Soja Granulat ,43.788
, 116 ,Sonnenblumenkerne ,0.267
, 116 ,Sonnenblumenkerne ,3.636
, 12 ,BAS hell ,0.975
, 12 ,BAS hell ,6.996
, 139 ,Vanille Aroma ,0.068
, 140 ,Weizenmehl Type W1600 ,1.163
, 140 ,Weizenmehl Type W1600 ,1.927
, 141 ,Weizenmehl Type W700 ,138.127
, 141 ,Weizenmehl Type W700 ,45.158
, 142 ,Walnüsse ,0.228
, 144 ,Wiechert Glutenfei ,1.160
, 145 ,Wienerwurst Stange ,0.100
, 150 ,Zitronen Aroma ,0.068
, 151 ,Zucker Normalkristall ,1.039
, 153 ,Wasser ,167.202
, 21 ,Dinkel Flocken ,0.347
, 24 ,Eier ganz ,0.453
, 26 ,Eigelb ProOvo ,0.365
, 29 ,Fenchel ganz ,0.105
, 36 ,Hafer ganz ,3.078
, 47 ,Hirse ganz ,0.133
, 49 ,Honig ,0.186]
```

So I have two questions:

1. How could I sort the array right?
2. How could I combine multiple entries to one entrie? f.e. not 140, 1.163 140, 1.927 => 140, 3,09 (I cannot do that earlier in my code because the array is a combination of 3 sql-result-arrays)

Here is my code:

```
s = Results2String(resultSet);

splitResult = s.split("/");
System.out.println(s);

s = null;
s = Results2String(resultSet2);
splitResult2 = s.split("/");
System.out.println(s);

s = null;
s = Results2String(resultSet3);
splitResult3 = s.split("/");
System.out.println(s);

System.out.println(splitResult3[0]);

preResult = new String[splitResult.length + splitResult2.length];

System.arraycopy(splitResult, 0, preResult, 0, splitResult.length);
System.arraycopy(splitResult2, 0, preResult, splitResult.length, splitResult2.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(preResult));

result = new String[splitResult.length + splitResult2.length + splitResult3.length];
System.arraycopy(preResult, 0, result, 0, preResult.length);
System.arraycopy(splitResult3, 0, result, preResult.length, splitResult3.length);

Arrays.sort(result);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Comment: Show us your code not the content of the array.

Comment: And what is *"the right sorting"*?

Comment: Currently, it seems sorted in lexicographic order based on the first number in each entry

Comment: this should be a 2-dimensinal array or 1-dimensonal which holds object of a class which you define

Comment: Right: 1,2,3,4,5,...60,70,80

Comment: That is some very ugly code.

Comment: what kind of values is in each result set? Does the first splitResult only contain the ids, the second one only the names and the third one only the floating point values? Or does each split result contain some `int`-`String`-`float`-combination?  
I can't (or don't want to) wrap my head around all this array copying stuff... sorry

Comment: They are all combinations of int-String-float

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that one of each `int`, `String` and `float` belong together.

So you should put them in one class and implement `Comparable` ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)):

```
public class Food implements Comparable<Food> {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float score; // or maybe kcal... ?

    public Food(int id, String name, float score) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Food other) {
        return id - other.getId();

        // use the following if you want to sort by name instead
        // return name.compareTo(other.getName());
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then you can sort an array of `Food`s....

---

### How to use

I'm still not sure what your `resultSet`s are (and why you have three of them) but I assume that they are [ResultSets from a database query](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html). Furthermore I assume that the `id`-`name`-`score`-combinations are actually rows in a database.

You could then go through those `ResultSet`s and put the values of each row in a `Food` object:

```
 ResultSet resultSet; // filled somewhere else
 List<Food> food = new ArrayList<Food>();

 while (resultSet.next()) {
     int id = resultSet.getInt(0); // assuming the ids are in the first column
     String name = resultSet.getString(1); // assuming the names are in the second column
     float score = resultSet.getFloat(2); // assuming the scores are in the third column

     food.add(new Food(id, name, score));
 }

 Collections.sort(food);
```

I hope this helps...

However, if your `resultSet`s are *really* ResultSets from a database query, then you should probably sort your values in your SQL query with `ORDER BY`...

Comment: Exactly this. Use a class to group the values, not an array with all of the values.

Comment: @PhilippSander since the class already implements `Comparator`, OP just need to use `Arrays#sort` i.e. no need to change the code.

Comment: When comparing numbers, you can simply use ``return id-other.id;`` instead of that long if/elseif/else structure.

Comment: but how should he use the class in his code? and how are you supposed to set the values for the fields? consider that the OP has probably a lower skill than you do

Comment: So the resultsets all return id-name-score in this combination and not resultset id, resultset name, resultset score

Comment: So every resultset return -> id name and score (the id, name and score are not split in different resultsets)

Comment: @user1993341 yeah ok, this is what I thought. Does the code work for you or do you still have some problems?

Comment: Right now i try to implement the Comparator, but it´s not that easy because i have never before worked with this.

Comment: I have the problem that when i´m using the implentation of comparable, i cannot use this to sort this because java is expecting an comparator. Ok Vielen Dank schon mal für die Hilfe. Ich schreib dir dann nachher.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a comparator method and use the Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T> method.  Here is a link to the [Collections java doc online](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

inside your comparator, split the line into 3 parts (int, string, float) and compare them as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Create an class with those three attributes.

```
public class Example{
    private int field1;
    private String field2;
    private double field3;
    .....
}
```

Fill you array with Objects made of this class then sort your array with a Comparator for this class that compares the String.